# Apollo Client Error: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am new to do this Apollo.

I am currently trying to get create an app with React and Apollo.

When I start my application, I am getting the following error:

Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

```
Here is my RegisterController -> index.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import { ChildMutateProps, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

interface Props {
  children: (
    data: { submit: (values: any) => Promise<null> }
  ) => JSX.Element | null;
}

class C extends React.PureComponent<ChildMutateProps<Props, any, any>> {
  submit = async (values: any) => {
    console.log(values);

    const response = await this.props.mutate({
      variables: values
    });

    console.log('response: ', response);

    return null;
  };

  render() {
    return this.props.children({ submit: this.submit });
  }
}

const registerMutation = gql`
  mutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    register(email: $email, password: $password) {
      path
      message
    }
  }
`;

export const RegisterController = graphql(registerMutation)(C);
```

Here is my main index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { client } from './apollo';
import { Routes } from './routes';
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Routes />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Finally, here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "@abb/controller",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

As you can see in my index.tsx, it is wrapped with ApolloProvider with the client passing in there.
Why I am getting this error?
Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`react-apollo` **HAS BEEN DEPRECATED**.

> React Apollo functionality is now directly available from
> @apollo/client

Read here:
https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo#readme

Apparently, the problem is with the **versions** of your packages (`apollo V3` group some client packages to avoid those issues). Read more: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/.

**Use apollo client v3** (Since June 2020)

Instead use `apollo-client`: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client.

command:

```
npm install @apollo/client
```

import:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
```

Follow this step-by-step example:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/

Comment: I have exactly the same code as @Eunicorn , I migrated to @apollo/client but for some reasons I still run into the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to fix this by passing a client value into the query hook, like this:

```
  import { appClient } from 'src/config/apollo'; //this is a config file in my repo where I'm defining the client location/info
  import { useGetMyDataQuery } from '../documents/GetMyData.generated'; // the React/Typscript file generated from the GraphQL query file
  ...
  const { loading, data, error } = useGetMyDataQuery({
    client: appClient,
  });
```

Whereas before the change, my query hook looked like this:

```
  const { loading, data, error } = useGetMyDataQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with downgrading `@apollo/client` from `v3.5.x` to `v3.4.17`, and my tests (which is where I got this error) started passing again.

`npm i @apollo/client@3.4.17`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was rendering on the server, therefore I needed to combine with a router and routes, ex:

*Browser*:

```js
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <BrowserRouter basename={basename}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </ApolloProvider>
```

*Server:*

```js
    <ConfigContext.Provider value={config}>
      <StaticRouter basename={config.app.URL} location={_event.path}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    </ConfigContext.Provider>,
```

If that's your case the following documentaion:

- https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/guides/ssr
- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/server-side-rendering/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I miss to wrap the component with `<ApolloProvider></ApolloProvider>` tags and define the client in it. My code after correction:

```
function rootFunction() {

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'api_url',
});

return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        your html code and your components here
    </ApolloProvider>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in my case helps to update react-hooks to v4

```
 "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0"
```