# Could not find "client"...Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

I am completely new to coding but jumping into blockchain development feet first. The issue I'm having was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65713544/apollo-client-error-could-not-find-client-in-the-context-or-passed-in-as-an-o). I tried everything mentioned, including reading through this [page](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/) - getting started with Apollo Client.

However, I'm getting the same error: *Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.*

[Screenshot noting the problem in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJCoz.png)

Here's my index.js code from the top to where the error is:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import EventCard from "../components/EventCard";
import Landing from "../components/Landing";
import client from "../apollo-client";


const UPCOMING_EVENTS = gql`
  query Events($currentTimestamp: String) {
    events(where: { eventTimestamp_gt: $currentTimestamp }) {
      id
      name
      eventTimestamp
      imageURL
    }
  }
`;


export default function Home() {
  const [currentTimestamp, setEventTimestamp] = useState(
    new Date().getTime().toString()
  );

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(UPCOMING_EVENTS, {
    variables: { currentTimestamp },
  });
```

***Solution 1: Go back to [Step 4](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#step-4-connect-your-client-to-react)***

That didn't work. Here's proof:

[Module not found - react.dom/client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liegM.png)

[Module not found - /.App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOIQX.png)

[React DOM not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDLmn.png)

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you're rendering `<Home>` outside of a `<ApolloProvider>`, but the `useQuery` hook requires that context. It seems you skipped over [Step 4: Connect your client to React](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#step-4-connect-your-client-to-react) in that tutorial - or if you did that, you haven't shown us the code of it.

Comment: @Bergi That didn't work. I tried it the first time. See my edited posts for screenshots.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Post your *entire* code as text. Where did you use `<ApolloProvider>`? And of course, you can't copy-paste the import statements from that tutorial into your custom project if you have a different project structure.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, my bad. Why no screenshots? 

I used <ApolloProvider> in my _apps.js file. After checking my _apps.js file, I realized I entered the same <ApolloProvider> component twice.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285554#285554

Comment: Thanks for that @Bergi. It looks like screenshots can be used, but only to prove a point or explain something that needs context. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

After checking my _apps.js file, I realized I entered my  components twice.

**Before:**

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
      <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains}>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </ApolloProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </RainbowKitProvider>
    </WagmiConfig>
  );
}
```

**After:**

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
      <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains}>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </RainbowKitProvider>
    </WagmiConfig>
  );
}
```